# Is it possible to use different Java version in one jenkins job?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Currently I face the issue that I need to run a two maven goals in a job with different Java version.

1st step is to compile my code with Java 6.
2nd step is to run Sonar with Java 8.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: did you try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38866362/1595977 ?

Comment: To this the answer is: [Toolchains](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html) which solves this problem. So running Maven with JDK 8 but compile/test the code with another JDK version for example with JDK 6..

Comment: Disclaimer. I can't use Java 8 to run maven for compiling. Our legacy codebase is not supporting it.

Comment: If you took the time to read khmarbaise answer you will see that using toolchains is a safe way to invoke a specifik jdk for specific goals, such as compile and test. That your buildscript runs with java8 does in no way mean that you compile with the same java executable. That is the purpose of toolchains. The below answer from rishikesh would potentially cause you this problem.

Comment: @NielsBechNielsen I rather hopped I could solve it on jenkins side only without the need to change the code base or everyones local setup.
Or am I missing something?
Are all maven plugins supporting this?

Comment: most. There may be some that does not, but most work seamlessly. Are you using any kind of code generation tools? jaxb or other? They could have an issue.

Comment: Of course you can have two steps in a jenkins job. One with a \java6\bin\java and one with a \java8\bin\java executable set but it probably requires some work, and the output may not be as good as one hopes. Upgrading a build to mvn3/java8 and keep a destination using toolchains is what I usually recommend legacy projects, since that would allow them to use newer tools (such as sonarqube)

Comment: @Niels Bech Nielsen, can you please share how my suggestion will cause this error?

Comment: Read the note at the bottom of https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html. The unintended use of a later API breaks this quite fast, and unfortunately shows first at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks for the other tips with [toolchain](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html) or `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target`.

For me that's sadly not working, but I found a simple solution for me. And that's using jenkins pipeline.

The workspace in that case is shared. It's created with the node command.

```
node('Slaves')
{
    stage('Build with coverage and All tests') {

    echo 'Starting build with ALL unittests'
        withMaven(jdk: 'JDK6') {
        //execute maven with java6
        }
    }
    stage('Execute Sonar') {
    //do other stuff
        withMaven(jdk: 'JDK8') {
        //execute maven with java8
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `java 8` as default and set below [properties](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) in your `pom.xml` to use `java 6` as a source and target compiler.

```
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

Comment: Corrected the `maven.compiler.source` version!